# Zero supported Devices in Google playstore (Supported devices section)

Tags: android, google-play

"Google play store is showing zero supported devices, I don't know why. I searched everywhere but didn't get the answer."

"I uploaded it in ALPHA version, I included testers list in it."

"I've tested it on my Samsung and it is showing an error:app is not compatible with this version,There's no reason for it to be incompatible with every single Android device."

## Here's my manifest file: ##

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="com.raphapp.tulyu" >


            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
            <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
            <permission
                android:name="com.raphapp.tulyu.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
                android:protectionLevel="signature" />

            <uses-permission android:name="com.raphapp.tulyu.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="vibrate" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
            <!-- FOR Storage -->
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE" />
            <!-- FOR Camera -->
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BILLING" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

            <!-- Don't require camera, as this requires a rear camera. This allows it to work on the Nexus 7 -->
            <uses-feature
                android:name="android.hardware.camera"
                android:required="false" />
            <uses-feature
                android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
                android:required="false" />
            <uses-feature
                android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
                android:required="false" />
            <uses-feature
                android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
                android:required="false" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"
                />

            <application
                android:name="com.raphapp.tulyu.app.AppController"
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:largeHeap="true"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:supportsRtl="true"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" >
                <activity
                    android:name="com.raphapp.tulyu.activity.Activity_SplashScreen"
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>


                <activity
                    android:name="com.raphapp.tulyu.activity.Activity_SignUp"
                    android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
                </activity>
                <activity
                    android:name="com.raphapp.tulyu.activity.Activity_Loading"
                    android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
                </activity>
                <activity
                    android:name="com.raphapp.tulyu.activity.Activity_SignIn"
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
                </activity>
                <activity
                    android:name="com.raphapp.tulyu.activity.Activity_FirstScreen"
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
                </activity>
                <activity
                    android:name="com.raphapp.tulyu.fragments.Fragment_Activity"
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
                </activity>
                <activity
                    android:name="com.raphapp.tulyu.activity.Activity_ContactDetails"
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
                <activity
                    android:name="com.raphapp.tulyu.activity.Tos"
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
                <activity
                    android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
                    android:configChanges="orientation"
                    android:label="@string/app_name"
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

                <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

                <receiver
                    android:name="com.raphapp.tulyu.receiver.CustomPushReceiver"
                    android:exported="false" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </receiver>
                <receiver
                    android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
                    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                        <!-- IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name. -->
                        <category android:name="com.raphapp.tulyu" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </receiver>

                <meta-data
                    android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
                    android:value="xxxxxx" />

                <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>


                <!-- Optionally, register AnalyticsReceiver and AnalyticsService to support background
              dispatching on non-Google Play devices -->
                <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
                    android:enabled="true">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </receiver>
                <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
                    android:enabled="true"
                    android:exported="false"/>

                <!-- Optionally, register CampaignTrackingReceiver and CampaignTrackingService to enable
                     installation campaign reporting -->
                <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
                    android:exported="true">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </receiver>
                <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />


            </application>

        </manifest>
```

#### Here's my build.gradle file:

```
    buildscript 
    {
        repositories {
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    repositories 
    {
        maven 
    { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.raphapp.tulyu"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 2
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies
     {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
        compile 'com.yalantis:ucrop:1.2.+'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        compile fileTree(include: 'Parse-*.jar', dir: 'libs')
        compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
        compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
        compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.+'
        compile 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
        compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.6@aar') {
            transitive = true;
        }
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    }
```

Comment: What is your `minSdk` version?

Comment: 19 and target is 23

Comment: anything to do with saying  ```<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />```
and then setting everything about the camera to false in uses-feature?

Comment: i did that for making it available for non camera mobiles too.

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="vibrate" />` do you mean  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />`?

Comment: yes i mean that. @KenWolf

Comment: add your build.gradle file contents here

Comment: Edit your question and add code of build.gradle file

Comment: @MuhammadUmair question updated

Comment: Don't post your fabric api key, but since you already did. Just delete the old one on the server and generate a new one.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk its ok . i already posted wrong key :-p

Comment: @ChKhurram Did you get solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that uses-feature is case sensitive.

You wrote two features in your manifest:

The first one is OK. You'd like to use a camera, but it is not required.

The problem is that the second requires an android.hardware.CAMERA, which is not present in any Android device. They have a camera, not a CAMERA.

**I hope this helps you.**
Hope you accept this answer ;)

Comment: log esy hi rating berhaty hain . mn tmhn b rate krn ga tmhara b level high ho jaye ga

Answer (score 0):

`uses-feature`  is case sensitive

use

```
        android:name="android.hardware.CAMERA"
```

instead of

```
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
```